# Como exportar archivos modificados con GIT Windows

Tags: git

Como puedo exportar todos los archivos modificados en un .zip. Necesito que sea  entre un rango de commits por ejemplo entre el commit inicial y el head. Encontre algunos codigos y he probado bastante pero en verdad no me funciona. Dejo un ejemplo de los codigos que no me han funcionado.

```
git archive -o export.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only commit1..commit2)

git diff --name-only commit1..commit2 | git archive -o export.zip HEAD
```